# Two Commands in a Launcher

Tags: xfce, .desktop

I researched this for a while, and couldn't find a solution.
What I'm trying to do is to create a launcher in the XFCE desktop environment which runs several commands:

```
cd Documents
./run_program.AppImage
```

I have tried the `&&` concatenation, but I don't know how to set the `""` to make it work. Do I also have to tell it that this is a bash command?

What I'm doing right now is to put this is a `.sh` script and run the script with `bash script.sh` in the launcher. That works. But can I run these directly?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you say you want to create a "launcher", could you specify which desktop environmane/window manager you are using?

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply use the full path to the script? Like `/home/JohnBig/Documents/run_program.AppImage`? Does the script _need_ to be run from within the `Documents` directory?

Comment: @Panki this is about desktop launchers, there's no shebang involved.

Comment: I am talking about desktop shortcuts in Linux Mint XFCE  (which the system calls "Launchers").

Comment: @terdon: No, it doesnt have to be run from a particular place. i just used that syntax because it happened to work.

Comment: So does using the full path in the launcher solve this?

Comment: Yes that works. Thanks. Funny I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

No the XFCE Launchers do not allow several commands to run directly. They are the usual [.desktop files](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html), so only one executable.

However, you should be able to run multiple commands by wrapping them in a shell, either in a shell script, or directly as:

```
sh -c "all; the; commands; you; may; ever; want; to; run..."
```